# QML menu bar display in QtQuick application

Tags: macos, qt, menu, qml

I'm developing a macOS application using QML containing just a menu bar:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Open...") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Save") }
            Action { text: qsTr("Save &As...") }
            MenuSeparator { }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Quit") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Edit")
            Action { text: qsTr("Cu&t") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Copy") }
            Action { text: qsTr("&Paste") }
        }
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&Help")
            Action { text: qsTr("&About") }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the menu doesn't look as expected:

[image: screenshot]

Usually, menu items appear next to the *Apple* menu which contains just *MenuTest* here:

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-issues.html#menu-bar) link could be useful.

Comment: I have a example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933297/customize-appmenu-in-qt/75387241#75387241

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the "stock" menu from `Controls` - it is not a "native" menu.

You can opt to use the one provided by [`Qt.labs.platform`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qt-labs-platform-menubar.html).

Keep in mind this will drag the QtWidgets module as a project dependency.

Comment: I don't find any example how to use *Qt.labs.platform*. Any idea?

Comment: I managed to fix my problem thanks to this link very close to yours: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-menubar.html